# Unable to load images on some mobiles with picasso android studio

Tags: android, picasso

I've built a android application that does not load images on some phones, but on some phones the images are loaded correctly.
i tried in my phone with android 6.0 and some device with high api and work currectly but in some device with low api such a 4.1.1 does not work and show error image.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageurl).fit().error(R.drawable.emptyimage).into(logoimg);
```

i see logcat in android studio a see this logs.

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4592K, 43% free 16403K/28487K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 18K, 36% free 18260K/28487K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 21.982MB for 4320012-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 22% free 22478K/28487K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 16ms
W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R7] Request{http://89.163.252.47/uploads/Ad_None/bf00eb37-b9b6-4348-a995-1ef884c358f8.jpg resize(454,375)}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R7]+5ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R7]+10ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R7]+15s 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R7]+15s 
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R7]+16s 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R7]+16s 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R7]+16s for error
D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R7]+17s 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R7]+17s
```

use from bitmap and unfortunately see this error in logcat.

```
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use Glide instead of Picasso it works well for low API devices.

1 . Add dependency inside gradle  as

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
}
```

2. Write this line where you want to use

```
  Glide.with(Context).load(imgUrl)
        .apply(new RequestOptions().override(200, 100)).into(imageView);
```

Comment: same problem -_-